# How to make a border-like frame with gaps and icons using CSS?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I managed to make a border-like frame using linear gradients. The frame has gaps in the corners and in the middle, for sake of decoration. Now I want to put icons in the middle of the each side of the frame (marked with red) but I couldn't find how to.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px;
}

header {
  background: linear-gradient( to right, transparent 10%, black 10%, black 40%, red 40%, red 60%, black 60%, black 90%, transparent 90%) 0 100%, linear-gradient( to right, transparent 10%, black 10%, black 40%, red 40%, red 60%, black 60%, black 90%, transparent 90%) 0 0, linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 20%, black 20%, black 40%, red 40%, red 60%, black 60%, black 80%, transparent 80%) 100% 0, linear-gradient( to bottom, transparent 20%, black 20%, black 40%, red 40%, red 60%, black 60%, black 80%, transparent 80%) 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1px, 100% 1px, 1px 100%, 1px 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p><i>An interesting subtitle</i></p>
</header>
```

I tried using pseudo-elements `::after` and `::before` to implement items in the middle. It worked. But I could only put items on two selected sides by using `::after` for one side and `::before` on the other side, however, it I need it on all four sides.

We can introduce extra HTML element to increase the number of pseudo elements we can use, but I am trying to solve this problem only with CSS to keep HTML source clean.

Comment: Why not put them as part of the background, suitably sized and positioned?

Comment: This can work. How can I generate such a background? Do you mind drafting an example?

Comment: I’m confined to an iPhone for a couple of days so cannot easily edit snippets. Try adding in a logo as the first part of background-image and sizing and positioning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one pseudo element and have multiple instance of your icon as a background.

Below I have used a radial-gradient but replace it with the url of your icon. I also optimized your gradients a little:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 20px;
}

header {
  --s: 20px; /* icon size */
  --icon: radial-gradient(red 71%,#0000 72%); /* change with the url of your image */
  --g: black calc(50% - var(--s)), #0000 0 calc(50% + var(--s)), black 0;
  --g1: linear-gradient(90deg,var(--g));
  --g2: linear-gradient(var(--g));
  background: 
  var(--g1) top   ,var(--g2) left, 
  var(--g1) bottom,var(--g2) right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 80% 1px, 1px 70%;
  position: relative;
}
header:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: calc(var(--s)/-2);
  background:
    var(--icon) top,
    var(--icon) bottom,
    var(--icon) left,
    var(--icon) right;
  background-size: var(--s) var(--s);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p><i>An interesting subtitle</i></p>
</header>
```

You can also do it without pseudo element but a more complex code:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 24px;
  margin: 20px;
}

header {
  --s: 20px; /* icon size */ 
  --icon: radial-gradient(red 71%,#0000 72%); /* change with the url of your image */
  border: calc(var(--s)/2) solid #0000;
  
  --g: black calc(50% - var(--s)), #0000 0 calc(50% + var(--s)), black 0;
  --g1:/80% 1px linear-gradient(90deg,var(--g));
  --g2:/1px 60% linear-gradient(var(--g));
  --g3:/var(--s) var(--s) var(--icon) border-box;
  background: 
   top    var(--g1),left  var(--g2),
   bottom var(--g1),right var(--g2),
   /**/
   top    var(--g3),
   bottom var(--g3),
   left   var(--g3),
   right  var(--g3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p><i>An interesting subtitle</i></p>
</header>
```